# Filling out an object across several pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User object which has about 50 fields.  I don't want all 50 fields on one form.  I want several pages to span the form.  How would I do that if only users/new.html.erb is all I know how to use to fill out a form.  What would I use for a second page, third page, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create partials and load every partial with Ajax (step1, step2, ..., stepN), or you can search and use a gem.

Check this railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked

http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: would you be able to give me some hints on how to load partials using Ajax?

Comment: If you do this manually, you can split your form into many forms stored in many partials (1 partial for each form). You can create a remote function that will be called each time you want to go forward or backward, passing 2 params, the id of the actual partial and the kind of action (if it is forward or backward moving). You may have 1 remote function, and call a JS to render the corresponding partial. Finally, you can store the object in a singleton, on a session variable.